# navbar change when scrolled with materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to replicate a navbar similar to this [website](http://kompas.com). so there is a non-sticky navbar when user opens the website and after user scrolled down a little bit the non-sticky navbar gone and replaced by a sticky navbar. how can I achieve something like this with materialize css ? so far i've only made the non-sticky navbar part

```
<nav class="nav-extended">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="viva.png" alt="" id="logo"></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
                <form>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input id="search" type="search" required>
                        <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons"></i></label>
                        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: try this http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="header">Header Example</div>
<div class="content">
<p>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur. 
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
header.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:-80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:8888;
    transition:0.3s top cubic-bezier(.3,.73,.3,.74);
}
body.on-scroll header.fixed {
    top:0;
}
.content {
    padding: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #333;
    min-height: 2700px; /* You can remove this,is just for demo purpose */
}
```

jquery:

```
  (function($){ 
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var $header = $(".header"),
            $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("fixed"));

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            $("body").toggleClass("on-scroll", (fromTop > 200));
        });
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn3qo58d/) example.

Comment: thank you, this one worked :) sorry for the late reply